# How to get changes text field values

Tags: asp.net

I have a web form that contain around 50 text box when user edit some of field out of them . i just want to get only those changes fields . how to get . please help me on this . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add Custom attribute in each `TextBox` to store the original value. This could be compared with `TextBox` Text attribute to know if original value is changed by user.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CustomeAttribute="Original Value" Text="Original Value"/>
```

After user submits changed values you can compare each TextBox Value with its `CustomAttribute`.

```
if(txt1.Attributes["CustomeAttribute"].ToString() != txt1.Text)
{
     //Value is changed by user.
}
```

To Add attributes from server side and assigning value.

```
txt1.Attributes.Add("CustomeAttribute", "your value");
```

This example is just to show how you can use Custom Attribute with single `TextBox` you can extend it for multiple textboxes.